# Ternary operator translation

Tags: c, ternary-operator

What would this translate to (in a more verbose way)?

```
local.sin_addr.s_addr = (!ip_address) ? INADDR_ANY:inet_addr(ip_address);
```

Trying to understand Ternary operators and I can't quite get it.

Comment: That's a basic construct of the language. Please see [a beginner's text book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to the question can be found in any beginner's text book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary is similar to an `if` statement, but it can be used where an expression is required. So it's equivalent to:

```
if (!ip_address) {
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
} else {
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternarys are used when you want to assign to a variable, and you have exactly two options.

The equivalent of:

```
int a = true ? 1 : 2;
```

Is:

```
int a;
if (true) {
    a = 1;
} else {
    a = 2;
}
```

Understanding this, you should be able to translate your code.

Comment: What does "you have exactly options" mean? Did you mean "you have exactly two options"?

Comment: @Barmar Whoops, sorry, yes. I'm extraordinarily tired. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Well ternary operators is a shorthand of your if/else statement. To explain the condition above it would look like this.

```
(condition) ? (return true value) : (return false value)
```

And this could be translated into a long form statement like @Carcigenicate answer.